# CakePHP 3: Missing route error for function that not exists

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

Why iam getting a "Missing Route" error for a function that not exists.

Inside `Reservations` Controller I have function `add` with one argument:

```
public function add($carid = null)
{
... 
}
```

Matching route:

```
Router::scope('/', function ($routes) {
Router::connect('/rentcar/:id', ['controller' => 'Reservations', 'action' => 'add'],['pass' => ['id'], 'id' => '[0-9]+']);
// rest of the routes not important 
...
});
Plugin::routes();
```

When I visit any page I see the following error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESX5I.jpg

The error message says:

> Error: A route matching "array ( 'controller' => 'Reservations',
>   'action' => 'add', 'plugin' => NULL, '_ext' => NULL, )" could not be
>   found.

...which is strange because I dont have function `add()` without arguments, instead, I have function `add($carid)` with one argument.

But when i add that route, everything works fine:

```
Router::connect('/rentcar2', ['controller' => 'Reservations', 'action' => 'add']);
```

What is going on?

Comment: When receiving errors, always post the _exact_ and _complete_ error message including the corresponding stacktrace! Also check **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782797/cakephp-3-missing-route-error-for-route-that-exists**, it's probably pretty much the same problem, you are somewhere trying to build a URL for the reservations/add action without passing an id.

Comment: @ndm There is an image above showing the exact and complete error message that i receive. and concerning that question, it's not the same, and conerning what you said about the URL for reservations/add, here is my code: `<?= $this->Html->link(__('Reservation'), ['controller' => 'Reservations','action' => 'add', $car->id]) ?> `

Comment: It shows the message but it's lacking the stacktrace. Without the latter it's impossible to tell where the problematic call can actually be found.

Comment: @ndm The desired action `reservations/add($carid)` is NOT being called from the current controller `reservations`,but from `cars` controller, that's why i specify a complete URL for the add($carid) function : `<?= $this->Html->link(__('Reservation'), ['controller' => 'Reservations','action' => 'add', $car->id]) ?`, but cakePHP doesn't recognize the passed parameter $car->id so that it match it with the route `Router::connect('/rentcar/:id', ['controller' => 'Reservations', 'action' => 'add'],['pass' => ['id'], 'id' => '[0-9]+']);`

Comment: The URL array you are showing here will match the shown route (even though it's being defined "wrongly" - `Router::connect()` calls aren't ment to be nested), so the problem is likely somewhere else, likely the same as in the linked question, but I'm not going to shoot in the dark further, so again, please show the stacktrace!

Comment: @ndm I'm just pointing to the problem so that it is going to be clear, yes the URL supposed to match the route but it does not, what you want me to show exactely? even I'm sure there is no error in the code.

Comment: @ndm Inside my routes.php there are only Router::connect() for each controller 's actions.so what exactely you want me to show?

Comment: The stacktrace associated with the error that you are receiving. It's shown on the left side, and can be found in a more copy & paste friendly format in the log files.

Comment: @ndm You are right, i found the error,it was in this line of code that is commented-out `<!-- .... <li role="presentation"><?= $this->Html->link(__('New Reservation'), ['controller' => 'Reservations', 'action' => 'add']) ?></li> -->` thanks a lot man.

Comment: @ndm Even i commented-out that code but it's causing the problem.thanks

Comment: That's because that is a HTML comment, not a PHP comment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in commented out HTML code which contains PHP code inside, code like this one:

```
<!-- <li role="presentation"><?= $this->Html->link(__('New Reservation'), ['controller' => 'Reservations', 'action' => 'add']) ?></li> -->
```

Which contains my old function without arguments `add` of `Reservations` Controller.
I deleted any similar code and everything worked fine.