# defined route is missing - Missing Route in Cakephp 3.4

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, admin, cakephp-3.4

I am trying to use the prefix "student". When I create a link in template or layout file I am getting this error as shown in the image:
[image]

code in routes.php

```
    <?php
use Cake\Core\Plugin;
use Cake\Routing\RouteBuilder;
use Cake\Routing\Router;
use Cake\Routing\Route\DashedRoute;

Router::defaultRouteClass(DashedRoute::class);

Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home']);
    $routes->connect('/pages/*', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display']);
    $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
});


Router::prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
   $routes->connect('/users/', [ 'controller' => 'MyUsers', 'action' => 'index', 'plugin'=>false]);
   $routes->connect('/login', [ 'controller' => 'MyUsers', 'action' => 'login', 'plugin'=>false, 'prefix'=>'admin']);
   $routes->connect('/', [ 'controller' => 'MyUsers', 'action' => 'dashboard', 'plugin'=>false]);
     $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
});

Router::prefix('trainer', function ($routes) {
   $routes->connect('/users/', [ 'controller' => 'MyUsers', 'action' => 'index', 'plugin'=>false]);
   $routes->connect('/login', [ 'controller' => 'MyUsers', 'action' => 'login', 'plugin'=>false]);
   $routes->connect('/', [ 'controller' => 'MyUsers', 'action' => 'dashboard', 'plugin'=>false]);
     $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
});


Router::prefix('student', function ($routes) {
   $routes->connect('/courses/', array ( 'controller' => 'Courses', 'action' => 'index', 'plugin' => false, 'prefix' => 'student', '_ext' => NULL, ));
   $routes->connect('/', array ( 'controller' => 'MyUsers', 'action' => 'dashboard', 'plugin' => false));
});

/**
 * Load all plugin routes.  See the Plugin documentation on
 * how to customize the loading of plugin routes.
 */
Plugin::routes();
```

layout file student.ctp has only one line of code:

```
<li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Courses', [ 'controller' => 'Courses', 'action' => 'index', 'plugin' => false, 'prefix' => 'student', '_ext' => NULL, ]);?></li>
```

AppController.php:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Cake\Controller\Controller;
use Cake\Event\Event;
use  Cake\Core\Configure;
use Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException;




class AppController extends Controller
{

    public $helpers = array(
        'CakeDC/Users.AuthLink',
        'CakeDC/Users.User',
        );


    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');
        $this->loadComponent('CakeDC/Users.UsersAuth');
        $this->loadComponent('Utils.GlobalAuth');

         $this->Auth->config('loginRedirect', array('controller'=>'Courses', 'action'=>'index', 'plugin'=>FALSE));
         $this->Auth->config('logoutRedirect', array('controller'=>'MyUsers', 'action'=>'login', 'plugin'=>FALSE));
         $this->Auth->config('unauthorizedRedirect', array('controller'=>'Courses', 'action'=>'index', 'prefix'=>$this->Auth->user('role')));
        $this->Auth->config('loginAction', array('controller'=>'MyUsers', 'action'=>'login'));  
         $this->Auth->allow(['login', 'logout']);



    }


    public function beforeRender(Event $event)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists('_serialize', $this->viewVars) &&
            in_array($this->response->type(), ['application/json', 'application/xml'])
        ) {
            $this->set('_serialize', true);
        }

        $this->_renderLayout();
    }

    private function _renderLayout()
    {
        $prefix =  isset($this->request->params['prefix'])?$this->request->params['prefix']:FALSE;

        if(!$prefix)
        {
            return;
        }

       $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout($prefix);



    }





}
```

I have checked this solution : [CakePHP 3: Missing route error for route that exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782797/cakephp-3-missing-route-error-for-route-that-exists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot feed the special `plugin` key with a boolean, it must either be `null`, or a string with the name of the plugin.

Also there is no need to define the `plugin` or `prefix` keys when connecting routes, the `Router::prefix()` method will take care of adding the prefix. Similarily `Router::plugin()` will add the plugin name, and when not using `Router::plugin()`, a default of `null` is being assumed for the `plugin` key.

Furthermore defining `_ext` with `null` only makes sense if you want to disallow generating URLs with extensions. And specifying it when generating URLs is only neccessary when it has been defined as a non-`null` value, which is also true for the `plugin` key (unless you need to break out of the current plugin context).

Long story short, connecting the route only requires the `controller` and `action` keys:

```
$routes->connect('/courses/', [
    'controller' => 'Courses',
    'action' => 'index'
]);
```

And generating the URL only needs the additonal `prefix` key, `plugin` is optional if not used in plugin context:

```
$this->Html->link('Courses', [
    'controller' => 'Courses',
    'action' => 'index',
    'plugin' => null,
    'prefix' => 'student'
]);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Routing > Prefix Routing](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing)**
- **[Cookbook > Routing > Plugin Routing](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#plugin-routing)**
- **[Cookbook > Routing > Routing File Extensions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#routing-file-extensions)**