# CakePHP 3.* Prefix routing error

Tags: cakephp, url-routing, cakephp-3.x

I made 3 tables namely `Roles`, `Users`, and `Blogs`. Roles have a 1 to many relationship with `Users` having a `role_id` foreign key, and likewise, `Users` have a one to many relationship with `Blogs` having the `user_id` foreign key. I initially baked all 3 users and everything was fine. I then decided to try prefixing `admin` for `Roles`.

```
Router::prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
    $routes->connect('/roles', ['controller' => 'Roles', 'action' => 'index]
)};
```

I made a folder inside the `Controller` folder (Controller > Admin) and put my `RolesController` there. I changed the namespace of my `RolesController` to `namespace App\Controller\Admin`. I also adjusted the file location of my `Roles` View files by putting it inside an Admin Folder (Admin > Roles > add.ctp, edit.ctp, index.ctp, view.ctp).

Everytime I try to access `localhost:8765/admin/roles`, I get an error message that says:

> Error: A route matching "array ( 'action' => 'add', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'plugin' => NULL, 'controller' => 'Roles', '_ext' => NULL, )" could not be found. None of the currently connected routes match the provided parameters. Add a matching route to config/routes.php
>
> The passed context was:
>
> ```
> [
>     '_base' => '',
>     '_port' => (int) 8765,
>     '_scheme' => 'http',
>     '_host' => 'localhost',
>     'params' => [
>         'pass' => [],
>         'controller' => 'Roles',
>         'action' => 'index',
>         'prefix' => 'admin',
>         'plugin' => null,
>         '_matchedRoute' => '/admin/roles',
>         '_ext' => null
>     ]
> ```

I am fairly new to cakephp, could someone please help me with this problem? Any advise would be much appreciated.

Comment: Whenever receiving errors, please always post **the _complete_ error**, that is, **including the _full_ stacktrace** (ideally copied from the logs where it is available in a properly readable fashion)! Also please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version (last line in `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt` or `lib/Cake/VERSION.txt`) - thanks! That being said, it's likely this: **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782797/cakephp-3-missing-route-error-for-route-that-exists**

Comment: Thank you very much, and will take note on the 'post the complete error' :)

Answer (score 1):

By adding `$routes->connect('/roles', ['controller' => 'Roles', 'action' => 'index]` you're only routing `/admin/roles` (index action) but not any other action of Roles.

If you only plan of having Roles in Admin then you should only add this line in your `Router::prefix` block:

```
$routes->connect('/roles/:action/*', ['controller' => 'Roles']);
```

Otherwise you should add a default fallback (as the `/` scope has) by adding this line: (note that it can be the only line in the `Router::prefix` block):

```
$routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
```

Your block will then look like that:

```
Router::prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
    $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
)};
```

See https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#fallbacks-method for more informations about fallbacks methods in CakePHP.